# How to implement interface using Java reflection or any other trick?

Tags: java, android, reflection, interface

Is there a way to implement interface which doesn't exist in Android SDK version that I'm using for development but exists in later Android versions through reflection or somehow else?

I need to implement interface "WebViewClassic.TitleBarDelegate" which (as well as class WebViewClassic) appeared in API-16, but don't exist in earlier API's.
How can it be done without upgrading development to API-16?

It must be implemented by my custom class derivative from WebView, because WebView implementation invokes methods of this interface.

So alternatively maybe some trick can be made to substitute one method to another in runtime at the moment of invocation?

Or maybe finally appeared some means to make releases for different API versions in one package?

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can take relevant files from the Android Sources and put them into your project? I've seen this for some classes when someone needed to tweak those classes a little. Not sure about your case though.

Comment: I could possibly take new implementation of webkit package or part of it, but as I understand it will tight my application with license limitations. Anyway, I don't think it will work, but thanks for idea.